# how to make searchview hint icon shown on query written?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-custom-view, searchview

There is a hint searchicon which appears when searchview edittext opens at the start of it like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgvXp.png) I want to show this hint icon  on searchview query currently when I query something this icon hides like [this](https://codingwithmitch.s3.amazonaws.com/static/blog/0554d5b6-2bcc-11e9-b183-2aabe8ede8eb/Filtering_RecyclerView_with_SearchView.png)

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: [That](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgvXp.png) could be a custom layout

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, the follow property is set to true. It depicts the default state of the SearchView. If true, it will be iconified when not in use and expanded when clicked.

```
app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
```